# How to insert data into one table from multiple table using oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have 6 different tables which has dependency with each other. I am trying to insert selected columns from all these 6 tables into a single table.

I have to pass a parameter to select the data from one table based on the output of the table reaming tables data's are fetched. If no records match then null should be passed.

I am trying to write a procedure using 6 cursor and pass the values of one cursor to others.

Somebody Pls help me achieve this.

Here is my simplifed verison of my table

```
 Table Name                         table type
 ==========                         ==========
 CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW         Linked_Table
 INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW     Linked_Table
 Intrfc_Motor_Office_Master         Linked_Table
 INTRFC_MOTOR_RISK_VIEW             Linked_Table
 Intrfc_Policy_view                 Linked_Table
 MO_CLAIM_MASTER                    Table

Selected Fields
===============
CRM_ACC_DATE_TIME,CRM_GEN_REP_NAME,CRM_SYSDATE
policy_number
Parent_office_name
CHASSIS_NO,ENGINE_NO,MAKE,MODEL,REGISTRATION_NO
AGENT_NAME,Branch_Office Description,Insured_Address,Insured_Name,PRODUCT_CODE,RISK_START_DATE,RISK_START_TIME
claim_no,DATE_OF_NOTIFICATION,notified_by,VEHICLE_TYPE

Condition
=========
mo_claim_master.crm_sl_no = CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW.crm_sl_no
INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW.claim_no = mo_claim_master.claim_no
intrfc_policy_view.branch_office_code = Intrfc_Motor_Office_Master.office_code
INTRFC_MOTOR_RISK_VIEW.refernce_num = intrfc_policy_view.num_reference_num
intrf_notification_view.refernce_num = intrfc_policy_view.num_reference_num
claim_ref_no=:claim_ref_no
```

INSERT INTO CFT_Table

---

i have created a procedure for the same but still i am not able to get the null values.
Is this a right way to get this output pl. suggest me.

```
      CREATE OR REPLACE
 PROCEDURE TEST(
     para_claim_ref_no IN VARCHAR2 )
 AS
   CURSOR c1
   IS
     SELECT claim_no,
       DATE_OF_NOTIFICATION,
       VEHICLE_TYPE,
       notified_by,
       notif_crm_sl_no
     FROM mo_claim_master
     WHERE claim_ref_no=para_claim_ref_no;
   t1 c1%rowtype;
   claim_num_var       VARCHAR2(50);
   notif_crm_sl_no_var NUMBER;
   CURSOR c2
   IS
     SELECT policy_num,
       reference_num
     FROM INTRFC_MOTOR_NOTIFICATION_VIEW
     WHERE claim_no=claim_num_var;
   t2 c2%rowtype;
   num_reference_num_var NUMBER;
   CURSOR c3
   IS
     SELECT BRANCH_OFFICE_CODE,
       Branch_Office_Desc,
       Insured_Name,
       Insured_Address,
       RISK_START_DATE,
       RISK_START_TIME,
       PRODUCT_CODE,
       AGENT_NAME
     FROM intrfc_policy_view
     WHERE num_reference_number=num_reference_num_var;
   t3 c3%rowtype;
   branch_office_code_var VARCHAR2(30);
   CURSOR c4
   IS
     SELECT OFFICE_CODE
     FROM INTRFC_MOTOR_OFFICE_MASTER
     WHERE office_code = branch_office_code_var;
   t4 c4%rowtype;
   CURSOR c5
   IS
     SELECT MAKE,
       MODEL,
       ENGINE_NO,
       CHASSIS_NO,
       REGISTRATION_NO
     FROM INTRFC_MOTOR_RISK_VIEW
     WHERE reference_num=num_reference_num_var;
   t5 c5%rowtype;
   CURSOR c6
   IS
     SELECT CRM_ACC_DATE_TIME,
       CRM_GEN_REP_NAME
     FROM CRM_CLAIM_INT_DETAILS_VIEW
     WHERE crm_slno=notif_crm_sl_no_var;
   t6 c6%rowtype;
 BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   FETCH c1 INTO t1;
   CLOSE c1;
   claim_num_var       := t1.claim_no;
   notif_crm_sl_no_var := t1.notif_crm_sl_no;
   OPEN c2;
   FETCH c2 INTO t2;
   CLOSE c2;
   num_reference_num_var := t2.reference_num;
   OPEN c3;
   FETCH c3 INTO t3;
   CLOSE c3;
   branch_office_code_var := t3.BRANCH_OFFICE_CODE;
   OPEN c4;
   FETCH c4 INTO t4;
   CLOSE c4;
   OPEN c5;
   FETCH c5 INTO t5;
   CLOSE c5;
   OPEN c6;
   FETCH c6 INTO t6;
   CLOSE c6;
   dbms_output.put_line(t1.claim_no);
   dbms_output.put_line(t1.DATE_OF_NOTIFICATION);
   dbms_output.put_line(t1.VEHICLE_TYPE);
   dbms_output.put_line(t1.notified_by);
   dbms_output.put_line(t2.policy_num);
   dbms_output.put_line(t3.Branch_Office_Desc);
   dbms_output.put_line(t3.Insured_Name);
   dbms_output.put_line(t3.Insured_Address);
   dbms_output.put_line(t3.RISK_START_DATE);
   dbms_output.put_line(t3.RISK_START_TIME);
   dbms_output.put_line(t3.PRODUCT_CODE);
   dbms_output.put_line(t3.AGENT_NAME);
   dbms_output.put_line(t4.office_code);
   dbms_output.put_line(t5.MAKE);
   dbms_output.put_line(t5.MODEL);
   dbms_output.put_line(t5.ENGINE_NO);
   dbms_output.put_line(t5.CHASSIS_NO);
   dbms_output.put_line(t5.REGISTRATION_NO);
   dbms_output.put_line(t6.CRM_ACC_DATE_TIME);
   dbms_output.put_line(t6.CRM_GEN_REP_NAME);
 END TEST;
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a cursor for that? I think you'd probably be able to just do an insert with a select with outer joins. It's hard to say without knowing more about your tables though.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post DDL to create your tables (or simplified versions of the tables), DML to insert some sample data, and an explanation of the expected output.  I'm not sure that I understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: i have edited my question by providing simplified tables. My output should be one record from selected columns from all six tables should get inserted into a seperate table.

Comment: Your cursors require no parameters, which means you probably don't need them as @flesk said. You can just join all the tables together and do a straight insert.

Answer (score 0):

No one posted an answer, so I'll add one here.

When you're talking about multiple cursors, it sounds like you want to loop over each row in each cursor, inserting and updating as you go. That's about the worst possible solution. You want an `INSERT ... SELECT`.

Tom Kyte explains this here: [Slow by slow...](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/10/slow-by-slow.html)

I'm not going to write the entire insert statement here, because you have a ton of table and columns, but basically you create an INSERT statement based on a SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO CFT_Table ( ... column names ... )
SELECT ( ... column names ... )
  FROM MO_CLAIM_MASTER
  LEFT JOIN Intrfc_Policy_view ON ( ... join condition ... )
  LEFT JOIN INTRFC_MOTOR_RISK_VIEW ON (... join condition ... )
```

I used LEFT JOINs because you said you wanted NULL values. I'm assuming MO_CLAIM_MASTER has one row for each row you want inserted.